# Benny Hill and his fire brigade in "Flying Machines"

Tags: magnificent-men-flying-machines, benny-hill-show

British comedian Benny Hill is known for one or more fire brigade skits in ["The Benny Hill Show"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063869) such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_WshqyjxEo). I was just re-watching ["Those Magnificent Men in their Flying Machines"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059797); Benny Hill appears in the movie as chief of an airfield fire brigade.

Although the movie was released in 1965 and "The Benny Hill Show" ran from 1969-1989, he had an earlier show (1962-1963). My question is: were the fire brigade sequences in the movie a reference to skits in his earlier show, or was it original to the movie and recycled in his later show?

Comment: What people find comedic definitely changes over the years.

Comment: Everything I can find says that "A Tribute to the Lower Tidmarsh Volunteer Fire Brigade" appeared in Season 12 Episode 2, sometime in 1970. So it would appear that the movie came first and Hill expanded upon the idea for his eponymous show. Not an answer as I can't seem to find anything concrete.